# calculate derivative $\frac{1}{2}(x+\alpha p)^T A(x+\alpha p)-b^T(x+\alpha p)$ about $\alpha$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $x,p$ are $n$ dimensional vector. 
Calculate the derivative $\frac{1}{2}(x+\alpha p)^T A(x+\alpha p)-b^T(x+\alpha p)$ about $\alpha$.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric and $b$ is also a $n$ dimensional vector

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{2}(x+\alpha p)^T A(x+\alpha p)-b^T(x+\alpha p)  = 
\frac{1}{2}p^T Ap \alpha^2 +(p^TAx-b^T p) \alpha+\frac{1}{2}x^TAx-b^Tx
$$

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \alpha}\left[\frac{1}{2}(x+\alpha p)^T A(x+\alpha p)-b^T(x+\alpha p)\right]=p^T A p \alpha + (p^TAx-b^T p)
$$